# strange errors in map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

Compiler says
**ERROR1: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "NAME::getName" object type is : const NAME**

**ERROR2: 'std::string NAME::getName(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from '_Ty1' to 'NAME &'**

on `cout << (it->first).getName();`

So why is that and how to make it work?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class NAME
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    NAME(string name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    map <NAME, int> telephoneBook = { {NAME("Alex"), 1122},
                                      {NAME("Oleg"), 3344} };

    for (auto it = telephoneBook.begin(); it != telephoneBook.end(); ++it)///вывод на экран
    {
        cout << (it->first).getName(); // error 1 and error2
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `getName()` function [should be `const`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns) because `map`'s keys are constants once inserted. Also, in the future please insert full error messages without omitting any information instead of "marking" corresponding lines and truncating messages.

Comment: `getName` is not declared `const`, which seems to be some of the problem. Also, sounds like you are not really using the right data structure or at least not the right kind of key and value.

Comment: @Sam I guess it should be an error as well, but that's not what OP is asking about.

Comment: The compiler should've also spewed out a bunch of errors, due to a lack of a meaningful `<` operator for the custom class, way before it got to these errors.

Comment: I don't truncated any errors, compiler gived me only two errors